# select running time on DataTable

Tags: c#, optimization, select, datatable, runtime

I need to use DataTable as a lookup table.
What is the running time on finding a data.
if I need range of m records
will it take O(log n) + O(m) ?

I have the following columns:

```
ItemID,
timeC, ...
```

My select must be:

```
Item = ___ && timeC between ___ and ___.
```

How can I improve the lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in which data you need to look up (and which indexes exist in the columns). Here is [an article](http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.com/2011/02/when-datatableselect-is-slow-use.html) describing how you can improve performance when selecting is too slow by using a `DataView`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you criteria for search, DataTables can have indexes, and may have primary keys defined, so the performance of finding a row is dependent of your search criteria IMO.

Comment: I have the following cloumns: ItemID, timeC, ...  My select must be: Item = ___ && timeC between ___ and ___. How can I improve the lookup?

Comment: Can you update your question with these kind of information please? It makes it much more useful and easier to help.